# Adding a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have added a bunch of columns to a DataGridView like this through code.

```
dgvDocDisplay.ColumnCount = 22;
dgvDocDisplay.Columns[0].Name = "Tag";
dgvDocDisplay.Columns[1].Name = "[ ]";
dgvDocDisplay.Columns[2].Name = "#";
dgvDocDisplay.Columns[3].Name = "Type";
dgvDocDisplay.Columns[4].Name = "Reference";
```

Now I want to make the 3rd column display checkboxes (the rows of that column, not the header). I did quite a bi of search and came across articles like [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-checkbox.htm) one but the method shown there would only insert a *new* column with checkboxes.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dgvDocDisplay.Columns.Add(col);
```

What I need is to add a checkbox column to an already existing column. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything regarding that.

How can I add checkboxes to an existing column?

Comment: I think you will have to remove that particular Column (using `RemoveAt`) and then insert a new one at your required index like `grid.Columns.Insert(index, new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn())`

Comment: if the datatype of your column is bit or Boolean, the column is displayed as checkBoxColumn automatically, Is it not working like that in your case??

Comment: Have you tried creating a DataTable object based on your xml and then binding it to the datagridview instead of creating each column individually?

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore I didn't know that. I still haven't bound the data to the DataGridView. Thanks for that piece of info :)

GxG: No, i was thinking of a more simpler way to go about it. I usually use DataReaders. Not DataTables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're adding the columns yourself, why not add the type of column you need when you do that? Like this:

```
dgvDocDisplay.Columns.AddRange(
    new DataGridViewColumn[]
    {
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Tag" },
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "[ ]" },
        new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { Name = "#" },
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Type" }
        // etc
    });
```

Comment: Tried this method and it works fine. I guess I'll go ahead with this one. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the current column from your collection and push in a new column of the desired type in that position.

you can use `grid.RemoveAt(yourindex);` to remove

then you can insert the desired one like

```
grid.Columns.Insert(yourindex, new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn())
```

Or you may just use `grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn())` and then set the `DisplayIndex` property of this column to your required index.

Comment: I tried this method and it does work. However it will make me repeat code many times because I have some more columns which needs to have checkbox columns apart from the one I showed here in my question. So I think its better to go with Flynn1179 method so that I can do it straight up only once. Thank you for your help nevertheless :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
dgvDocDisplay.Columns[2] = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
```

?

this

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dgvDocDisplay.Columns.Add(col);
```

indeed adds a new column thus the Columns.Add()

Comment: It is a get property, this won't even compile ! ! you can use comments to seek clarifications

Comment: Then maybe use the new declaration instead of declaring the count of the columns.